# Why does this if statement continue to execute?

Tags: jquery, offset, flags, scrolltop

I've got a page made of several sections (think a classic parralax setup). Now that I have it all built I want to start making certain parts do cool things when I scroll to them.

In my ignorance I assume that means I'll need to get the offset().top for each position and compare it to the window's scrollTop().

Here is what I have going on, as an example:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

    var scrollPosition = $(this).scrollTop();
    var sectionFourPosition = $('.slideFour').offset().top;

    var sectionFourFlag = 0;

    if( sectionFourFlag == 0 && scrollPosition >= sectionFourPosition  ){
        alert("You Passed the Top of Section Four");
        sectionFourFlag++;
    };

    $('.ScrollPositionDisplay').text(scrollPosition);
    $('.SectionFourOffsetDisplay').text(sectionFourPosition);
    $('.SectionFourFlagDisplay').text(sectionFourFlag);

});
```

I've got a little panel I use to show me the state of various variables in my project. I have the sectionFourFlag there as I only want this to execute the one time. I figure I can then flip the flag to 1 and that should break the IF statement...

No such luck. It keeps running despite the Flag showing as one. So for every incirment I scroll past the "sectionFourPosition", the alert goes of again, and again, and again...

This SEEMS like it should work, and my GoogleFu has failed me.

What have I left out?

Answer (score 1):

You did good, with one error:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

    var scrollPosition = $(this).scrollTop();
    var sectionFourPosition = $('.slideFour').offset().top;

    var sectionFourFlag = 0;

    if( sectionFourFlag == 0 && scrollPosition >= sectionFourPosition  ){
        alert("You Passed the Top of Section Four");
        sectionFourFlag++;
    };

    $('.ScrollPositionDisplay').text(scrollPosition);
    $('.SectionFourOffsetDisplay').text(sectionFourPosition);
    $('.SectionFourFlagDisplay').text(sectionFourFlag);

});
```

You are resetting your `sectionFourFlag` every time you scroll. You should put the `var sectionFourFlag = 0;` outside the scroll function, like:

```
var sectionFourFlag = 0;

$(window).scroll(function(){

    var scrollPosition = $(this).scrollTop();
    var sectionFourPosition = $('.slideFour').offset().top;

    if( sectionFourFlag == 0 && scrollPosition >= sectionFourPosition  ){
        alert("You Passed the Top of Section Four");
        sectionFourFlag++;
    };

    $('.ScrollPositionDisplay').text(scrollPosition);
    $('.SectionFourOffsetDisplay').text(sectionFourPosition);
    $('.SectionFourFlagDisplay').text(sectionFourFlag);

});
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time out of your day to help.

Answer (score 0):

This is your issue:

```
var sectionFourFlag = 0;

if( sectionFourFlag == 0 && scrollPosition >= sectionFourPosition  ){
```

The part `sectionFourFlag == 0` can never be false while you define `sectionFourFlag` within your JavaScript; you need to initialise it outside of this procedure.

Comment: So, if I understand I need to declare it outside of " $(window).scroll(function() "? Becasue... each time I scroll, while it's in here, I am setting it BACK to 0?

I hope I am closer to grokking this.

Comment: Pretty much spot on, yes. If you define it outside of the procedure, it won't reset and your code will work as you're expecting it to.

Comment: Thank you for taking time out of your day to help. I think I understand a bit better now.

Comment: Happy to help. If either answer did solve your problem, it would be helpful to future users with the same issue to accept one of them, to avoid your question being considered "unanswered".